# How could a user check for permission to view their "friends" image without the image having a list of permissible friends in it's database.

Tags: php

I'm thinking of Facebook. I don't need PHP code yet, just an understanding of how to achieve the following in PHP.

Let's say I have `user A` who has a friend `user B` with permissions set to `friend`. `User A` wants to view `user B's` image, an image that has permissions set to `friends` only. How do you check to see if `user A` is a friend of `user B`, and able to view the image without searching through a list of friends?

I'm thinking that each image must have a list of permissible friends in it's database record, which could have thousands of names in each image record. And you test the user by checking to see if `user A's` name is in the image's database record with a wildcard.

But this means that each image `user B` has, must have his entire list of friends, in each record, in every row of images.

This seems ridiculous and I'm wondering if there's another way to test if they are friends and if the image is ok for `user A` to view.

Is there another way to test for `friends` so that `user A` can view the image without having to fill each image row up with a friends list?

Comment: "without searching through a list of friends" - a question: why?

Comment: There must be someway to check that they have permissions without having to have each image holding an entire list of friends, in each row of the database.

Comment: you keep repeating "each image holding an entire list of friends", but I'm curious why would you insist on such a requirement? it's fairly enough to keep, for each image, just the list of permissions (not list of friends) which the visiting user needs to satisfy in order to see that image

Answer (score 0):

Simply intersect the permissions on user A with permissions on user B's image and see if you have any result?

Comment: That's the problem. Each image in user B's database would have to have to have an entire friend's list in each record. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No. Each image would only have a list of needed permissions (friends, public, onlyme, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Create table in DB `users_friends` with columns `user_id` and `friend_user_id` (this is place where you store information about your user firends) and before return image check this table.

Comment: I thought of this, and I thought of it as a `relationship` DB. However that means that there would be thousands upon thousands of relationships to check through because there would be a relationship record for every friend, friend's friend and so on wouldn't there?

Comment: @ax.falcon You need somewhere store information about your friends. DB is good choice. Check `users_firends` table to get info that user_A is frient of user_B will be VERY FAST. (db uses index-es to improve performance)

Answer (score 0):

I figure that the user's have to be tested at least once to see if they're friends, for example, when `user A` visits `user B's` profile. At that point they can be tested and then the test giving a `true` variable can be passed around the entire of `user B's` profile, meaning that they wouldn't have to test more than once and, it means each image doesn't have to have an entire list of friends in each record.